# React Native Context rendering a blank screen when wrapped inside <Provider>

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router, react-context

I'm trying to build a simple blog native app using context and have stumbled upon an issue to which I can't find a root to.

Here's the structure of it:

/context/createDataContext.js file:

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react"; 
export default (reducer, actions, initialState) => {
const Context = React.createContext();
const Provider = ({ childern }) => {
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
const boundActions = {};
for (let key in boundActions) {
  boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch);
}
return (
  <Context.Provider value={{ state, ...boundActions }}>
    {childern}
  </Context.Provider>
);
};
return { Context, Provider };
};
```

/context/BlogContext.js:

```
import createDataContext from "./createDataContext";

const blogReducer = (state, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
case "add_blogpost":
  return [...state, { title: `Blog Post Number ${state.length + 1}` }];
default:
  return state;
}
};
const addBlogPost = (dispatch) => {
return () => {
dispatch({ type: "add_blogpost" });
};
};
export const { Context, Provider } = createDataContext(
blogReducer,
{ addBlogPost },
[]
);
```

/screens/IndexScreen.js :

```js
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList, Button } from "react-native";
import { Context } from "../context/BolgContext";

const IndexScreen = () => {
  const { state, addBlogPost } = useContext(Context);

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Add a blod post" onPress={addBlogPost} />
      <FlatList
        data={state}
        keyExtractor={(blogPost) => blogPost.title}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return <Text>{item.title}</Text>;
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default IndexScreen;
```

And finally App.js :

```js
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import IndexScreen from "./src/screens/IndexScreen";
import { Provider } from "./src/context/BolgContext";
import React from "react";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {
        <Provider>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Home"
              component={IndexScreen}
              options={{ title: "My app" }}
            />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </Provider>
      }
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Now I did some debugging, even though the code does't come back with any error, but the issue seems to be on my Provider, since if I remove it I can see content on the screen. Does anybody know why this happens.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happens with create-react-app v16 too

Comment: @jacopo will you be able to solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the Provider method like below

Form

```
const Provider = ({ childern }) => {
```

To

```
const Provider = (props) => {
```

Then you can destructure while passing to the content.provider like below

```
    <Context.Provider value={{ state, ...boundActions }}>
    {props.childern}
  </Context.Provider>
```